# How does reset_postdata restore the post of the main query loop?

Tags: wp-query, wp-reset-postdata

How does `reset_postdata` works? The docs say:

> restore the global $post variable of the main query loop after a
>   secondary query loop using new WP_Query

But in the class, it takes the "current" post of the current `WP_Query` instance, and set it as the global `$post`. So how does it restore the post of the main query loop?

The [`WP_Query` class](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.1/src/wp-includes/query.php).

Comment: It _seems_ like the [`global $wp_query` doesn't change](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.1/src/wp-includes/query.php#L122) but the `global $post` object gets overwritten and `wp_reset_postdata()` uses the `global $wp_query` to reset the original `$post` object. Hopefully someone with more knowledge of core can come in and submit a legitimate answer though.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee the global `$wp_query` never changes, except if you use `query_posts` or if you use `$wp_query` as a local variable. As for the rest of your comment, you are nearly spot on

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`WP_Query::reset_postdata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/reset_postdata/) sets the global post variable (*`$GLOBALS['post'] === $post`*) to the current post in the loop of the current `WP_Query` instance.

```
public function reset_postdata() {
    if ( ! empty( $this->post ) ) {
        $GLOBALS['post'] = $this->post;
        $this->setup_postdata( $this->post );
    }
}
```

What that means is that, if you run a custom query on a page, `$post` will hold the last post in the loop of that custom query. That you can test yourself by adding

```
?><pre><?php var_dump($post); ?></pre><?php
```

directly after the loop of your custom query.

The same is true for the main query after the loop, `$post` will hold the last post of the main query and the first post in the loop before the loop.

Here is a simple test to test the `$post` global. You can add this into your functions file and load any page on your site

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function()
{
    global $post;
    ?><pre><?php var_dump($post->ID); ?></pre><?php
}):
add_action( 'wp_footer', function()
{
    global $post;

    ?><pre><?php var_dump($post->ID); ?></pre><?php 

    $q = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=3' );
    while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
        $q->the_post();

        ?><pre><?php var_dump($post->ID); ?></pre><?php 
        the_title();

    }   

    ?><pre><?php var_dump($post->ID); ?></pre><?php 
    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?><pre><?php var_dump($post->ID); ?></pre><?php 
});
```

> So how does it restore the post of the main query loop?

That is done by calling [`wp_reset_postdata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_reset_postdata/) which resets the global `$post` to the current post in the loop of the main query. This is usually the first of last post depending if you add your custom query before or after the main query loop.

Lets look at how `wp_reset_postdata()` does it

```
function wp_reset_postdata() {
    global $wp_query;

    if ( isset( $wp_query ) ) {
        $wp_query->reset_postdata();
    }
}
```

As you can see, `wp_reset_postdata()` is just a wrapper for `WP_Query::reset_postdata()`. The important part here is that it is a wrapper for the main query's object method, `$wp_query->reset_postdata();`.

Remember, the main query also uses `WP_Query`. Here is how the main query object is set

```
/**
 * WordPress Query object
 * @global WP_Query $wp_the_query
 * @since 2.0.0
 */
$GLOBALS['wp_the_query'] = new WP_Query();

/**
 * Holds the reference to @see $wp_the_query
 * Use this global for WordPress queries
 * @global WP_Query $wp_query
 * @since 1.5.0
 */
$GLOBALS['wp_query'] = $GLOBALS['wp_the_query'];
```

So what `wp_reset_postdata()` do is, it takes the current post in the main query object and sets that as the `$post` global, and that is how `WP_Query::reset_postdata()` sets `$post` to the current post of the main query

Comment: Thanks, ok, I thought wp_query was reused by our second query, but wp_query is not changed. I get it now, thanks.